# This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"

Tags: macos, python-3.x, bundle, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I think I did everything I could in the last 20 hours, but nothing seems to work. My app is running and working -- just as it should -- the only problem I have is that I cannot create a `.app` bundle from it. I tried both `Py2App` and `cx_Freeze` but non of them is working. Because of the multi-platform support I would stick with the latter -- if possible.

The `setup.py` looks like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

OPTIONS = {'build_exe': {'includes': ['sip',
                                      'PyQt5',
                                      'PyQt5.QtCore',
                                      'PyQt5.QtGui',
                                      'PyQt5.QtWidgets',
                                      'PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets',
                                      'PyQt5.QtMultimedia',
                                      'PyQt5.QtNetwork']}}

EXECUTABLES = [Executable('main.py', base=base)]
NAME = 'coublet'
VERSION = '0.5.70'

setup(name = NAME,
      version = VERSION,
      options = OPTIONS,
      executables = EXECUTABLES)
```

The error message I have is this:

```
objc[28404]: Class NotificationReceiver is implemented in both
/Users/.../build/coublet-0.5.70.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWidgets and
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets. One of
the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fc4b96e98b0) is not the object's thread
(0x7fc4b95dbc80).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7fc4b96e98b0)

On Mac OS X, you might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process.
Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt
platform plugin "cocoa".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort trap: 6
```

My system Info:

```
Mac OS X  : 10.9.4
Python    :  3.4.1
cx_Freeze :  0.9
PyQt5:    :  5.3.1
- - -
Packages installed via: Homebrew and PIP
```

`.app` structure:

```
build/coublet-0.5.70.app
└── Contents
    ├── Frameworks
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   ├── PyQt5.QtCore.so
    │   ├── PyQt5.QtGui.so
    │   ├── PyQt5.QtMultimedia.so
    │   ├── PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets.so
    │   ├── PyQt5.QtNetwork.so
    │   ├── PyQt5.QtWidgets.so
    │   ├── Python
    │   ├── QtCore
    │   ├── QtCore.so
    │   ├── QtGui
    │   ├── QtGui.so
    │   ├── QtMultimedia
    │   ├── QtMultimedia.so
    │   ├── QtMultimediaWidgets
    │   ├── QtMultimediaWidgets.so
    │   ├── QtNetwork
    │   ├── QtNetwork.so
    │   ├── QtOpenGL
    │   ├── QtWidgets
    │   ├── QtWidgets.so
    │   ├── _bisect.so
    │   ├── _bz2.so
    │   ├── _codecs_cn.so
    │   ├── _codecs_hk.so
    │   ├── _codecs_iso2022.so
    │   ├── _codecs_jp.so
    │   ├── _codecs_kr.so
    │   ├── _codecs_tw.so
    │   ├── _datetime.so
    │   ├── _hashlib.so
    │   ├── _heapq.so
    │   ├── _json.so
    │   ├── _lzma.so
    │   ├── _md5.so
    │   ├── _multibytecodec.so
    │   ├── _opcode.so
    │   ├── _pickle.so
    │   ├── _posixsubprocess.so
    │   ├── _random.so
    │   ├── _scproxy.so
    │   ├── _sha1.so
    │   ├── _sha256.so
    │   ├── _sha512.so
    │   ├── _socket.so
    │   ├── _ssl.so
    │   ├── _struct.so
    │   ├── array.so
    │   ├── binascii.so
    │   ├── grp.so
    │   ├── imageformats
    │   │   ├── libqdds.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqgif.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqicns.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqico.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqjp2.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqjpeg.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqmng.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqsvg.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqtga.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqtiff.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqwbmp.dylib
    │   │   └── libqwebp.dylib
    │   ├── libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
    │   ├── liblzma.5.dylib
    │   ├── library.zip
    │   ├── libreadline.6.dylib
    │   ├── libssl.1.0.0.dylib
    │   ├── main
    │   ├── math.so
    │   ├── platforms
    │   │   ├── libqcocoa.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqminimal.dylib
    │   │   └── libqoffscreen.dylib
    │   ├── pyexpat.so
    │   ├── readline.so
    │   ├── select.so
    │   ├── sip.so
    │   ├── termios.so
    │   ├── time.so
    │   ├── unicodedata.so
    │   └── zlib.so
    └── Resources
```

The question is I think pretty obvious: what am I doing wrong? (or what am I not doing?)

Comment: Just a suggestion: you can temporarily remove /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (e.g. by renaming it or remove via homebrew). It should let you to successfully build the app bundle.

Comment: I got the same on Windows. I have to add `libEGL.dll` to the main application directory myself. So maybe there is similar dynamic library on OS X?

Answer (score 7):

When building an app with `cx_Freeze` on MacOSX all dependent libraries (`.so` files on MacOSX) are packaged into the application bundle. It is this that makes the application portable to other systems, without requiring a second install of Qt.

When launching the Application, the libraries should therefore be loaded from within the bundle. However, in your case the system libraries are still being loaded:

```
/Users/.../build/coublet-0.5.70.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWidgets
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
```

The result `One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.` means that either of these could be loaded. If it picks the correct one, great! If it doesn't you've got two separate sets of libraries loading simultaneously, and that fails shortly afterwards. As an aside, you may find that if you try your Application on another system it will work fine! *Sometimes*.

For an overview of the problem I suggest taking a look at the following [bug #33](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/33/handle-qt-5-platform-plugins).

### Before you begin

Make sure you have an up-to-date version of [cx_Freeze](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze) installed. I would suggest trying to clone the repository and installing from there.

Secondly, ensure that the Qt plugins are being correctly built into your application. Cx_Freeze previously looked for the `qt-menu.nib` file to determine if it was building a Qt application. This is no longer available in Qt5, but you can pass it on the command-line when building your app. Set it to whatever you want, it really doesn't matter:

```
python setup.py bdist_mac --qt-menu-nib=/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/plugins/platforms/
```

This may be enough to fix your problem. But if not, you have two options:

### Option 1

Each library file contains the paths to it's dependencies. If you're receiving this error, it means some of those paths are either a) still pointing to the original file, or b) not specific enough (and being found on your `PATH` or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`).  However, you can re-write paths using `install_name_tool` from the command line (as described [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/33/handle-qt-5-platform-plugins#comment-4225118):

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets @executable_path/QtWidgets build/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/qt_plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore @executable_path/QtCore build/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/qt_plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport @executable_path/QtPrintSupport build/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/qt_plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/QtGui build/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/qt_plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
```

This rewrites the paths in the libraries to point into your application folder, using `@executable_path` as the base. You will need to do this for all the paths that you find loading incorrectly. I'd suggest wrapping it up into an script, to run automatically after the build.

If you want to look at which libraries a file is referencing you can use `otool`. For example, in a successfully built application of mine:

```
otool -L libqcocoa.dylib 
libqcocoa.dylib:
    @executable_path/../Resources/qt_plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 20.0.0) 
...
```

There was an [updated workaround in the issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/33/handle-qt-5-platform-plugins#comment-13307625) that suggests that just importing the correct module in your app will get it to function, however it seems unlikely that you've made an application without `QtWidgets`.

### Option 2

If the above doesn't work, there is another approach outlined [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/32). This is a bit of a sledgehammer approach in that it simply prevents loading of plugins at all.

- Add a `qt.conf` file next to the executable (in the `.app` bundle that contains:
  `[Paths]
  Plugins = '.'`
- Either set the environment variable `QT_PLUGIN_PATH=""` (you can do this within your application before importing `PyQt`. Or call `QtGui.QApplication.setLibraryPaths([])` before creating your application object.

The result is no plugins, so your application will not have access to the MacOSX Cocoa style and UI (e.g. file, colour dialogs).

Comment: Great answer.
Can you please have a look in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858376/creating-dmg-for-qt-app-mac-osx

Comment: file: dist/fullmain.app/Contents/MacOS/qt_plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 5):

Use this command :

```
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

It resolved the same issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This is in addition to @mfitzp's answer.

This [QT Plugins Document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#qt-plugins) came in handy.

To look for default locations that your QT app is trying to search you can use following command:

```
$sudo dtruss MacOS/ncher 
  getattrlist("/ncher.app\0", 0x7FFF954B51A4, 0x7FFF5C8FDD20)              = 0 0
  getattrlist("/ncher.app/Contents\0", 0x7FFF954B51A4, 0x7FFF5C8FDD20)             = 0 0
  getattrlist("/ncher.app/Contents/MacOS\0", 0x7FFF954B51A4, 0x7FFF5C8FDD20)               = 0 0
  stat64("/ncher.app/Contents/MacOS\0", 0x7FFF5C8FDED8, 0x7FFF5C8FDD20)            = 0 0
  stat64("/ncher.app/Contents/MacOS/platforms/.\0", 0x7FFF5C8FDF58, 0x7FFF5C8FDD20)                = -1 Err#2
  open("/dev/tty\0", 0x1000000, 0x1FF)             = 5 0
  fcntl(0x5, 0x2, 0x1)             = 0 0
  close(0x5)               = 0 0
  write_nocancel(0x2, "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin \"cocoa\".\n\nReinstalling the application may fix this problem.\n\0", 0x97)              = 151 0
  sigprocmask(0x3, 0x7FFF5C8FE6B4, 0x0)            = 0x0 0
  __pthread_sigmask(0x3, 0x7FFF5C8FE6C0, 0x0)              = 0 0
  __pthread_kill(0x603, 0x6, 0x0)          = 0 0
  kevent64(0x4, 0x0, 0x0)          = -1 Err#4
```

You can see this QT app trying to look into `MacOS/platforms`, once i copied my  libqcocoa.dylib plugin (its path were modified by `install_name_tool` command as per @mfitzp's answer) there, my application worked like charm.

BTW it is advisable by [MAC codesigning guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG201) to have this directory structure correctly setup,

#### DONT put Frameworks, plugins in `ncher.app/Contents/MacOS` directory

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Your link actually helped!

Comment: Can you please have a look in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858376/creating-dmg-for-qt-app-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the context of just starting a Qt Widgets app from Qt Creator.

What helped me was to set the variable `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` to the value `<Qt-dir>/plugins` (where `<Qt-dir>` is the absolute path to the folder in the Qt directory containing, among others, `bin`, `doc`, `include`, `lib` and of course `plugins`).

This probably did not fix the root cause of the problem but it was a quick fix that's working fine so far.