# QT5.5 'failed to load platform plugin "cocoa"' - MacOS 10.9

Tags: macos, qt, cocoa, pyqt4

I am using ete3 (tree visualization) library, which has PyQT as one of its dependencies. When I try to render a tree (tree.render), which access Qt libraries, it fails and gives me the error:

```
"This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa".
Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort trap: 6"
```

I have checked the [existing discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188153/this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platfo) and also the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#qt-plugins) regarding this, but changing the plugin path in qt.conf didn't help.

```
  Process:         Python [22195]
  Path:            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Identifier:      Python
  Version:         2.7.6 (2.7.6)
  Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
  Parent Process:  bash [8443]
  Responsible:     eclipse [8418]
  User ID:         502

  Date/Time:       2016-03-15 16:30:05.179 +1300
  OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F1603)
  Report Version:  11
  Anonymous UUID:  0BEE0024-9A4E-5B22-7A56-EB2C12CF1FC2


  Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

  Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
  Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

  Application Specific Information:
  abort() called

  Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f7bf866 __pthread_kill + 10
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89c2a35c pthread_kill + 92
  2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92067b2e abort + 125
  3   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000103e60ab9 qt_message_fatal(QtMsgType, QMessageLogContext const&, QString const&) + 9
  4   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000103e62487 QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 231
  5   org.qt-project.QtGui            0x000000010388d527 QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() + 6359
  6   org.qt-project.QtGui            0x000000010388d54b QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() + 27
  7   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010401d4ec QCoreApplication::init() + 204
  8   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010401d407 QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) + 39
  9   org.qt-project.QtGui            0x000000010388a9ee QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(QGuiApplicationPrivate&) + 14
  10  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x00000001044689ee QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) + 206
  11  QtGui.so                        0x0000000103365a33 init_type_QApplication(_sipSimpleWrapper*, _object*, _object*, _object**, _object**, _object**) + 179
  12  sip.so                          0x0000000105403262 sipSimpleWrapper_init + 197
  13  org.python.python               0x0000000100075f55 type_call + 245
  14  org.python.python               0x000000010000c742 PyObject_Call + 98
  15  org.python.python               0x00000001000c0430 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12368
  16  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4786 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2118
  17  org.python.python               0x00000001000c2bc0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22496
  18  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4786 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2118
  19  org.python.python               0x00000001000c2bc0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22496
  20  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4786 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2118
  21  org.python.python               0x00000001000c2bc0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22496
  22  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4786 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2118
  23  org.python.python               0x00000001000c48a6 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
  24  org.python.python               0x00000001000e912e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
  25  org.python.python               0x00000001000e93ca PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
  26  org.python.python               0x000000010010044d Py_Main + 3101
  27  org.python.python               0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

  Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f7c0662 kevent64 + 10
  1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff93213421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
  2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff93213136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

  Thread 2:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f7bfe6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89c2af08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89c2dfb9 start_wqthread + 13

  Thread 3:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f7bfe6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89c2af08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89c2dfb9 start_wqthread + 13

  Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
    rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff77830310  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbfe578  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
    rdi: 0x0000000000000d07  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfe5a0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfe578
     r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fff5fbfe400  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
    r12: 0x00000001041696b8  r13: 0x0000000106d34b20  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000103540510
    rip: 0x00007fff8f7bf866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000103edfc50

  Logical CPU:     0
  Error Code:      0x02000148
  Trap Number:     133
```

I have installed all my libraries (Qt5.5, PyQt4, SIP4.17, ete3) in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. The libraries have all been installed fine, except when an external library tries to find the plugin, it can't find it.

I am new to Python and Qt libraries, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was debugging the code in Eclipse, and found that it throws exception at this line: _QApp = QtGui.QApplication(["ETE"])

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem sorted. It is actually a false error raised by Qt version 5.5. The new version expects to include QtDBus.framework in your app, otherwise it crashes.

An [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48015) has already been raised for this.

I installed the previous version of Qt (5.4.2), and it works like a charm.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Hi! How did you downgrade QT? I'm having the same issue... Thanks.