# Class is implemented in both places when using py2app

Tags: python, pyqt5, py2app

I am trying to make a standalone application using `py2app` with `python3`:

```
python3 setup.py py2app --packages=PyQt5
```

Everything seems to work just fine. But when one launches the application, the following errors are caught in Mac console:

```
14/04/16 13:27:27,688 app[98583]: objc[98583]: Class RunLoopModeTracker
is implemented in both   
/Users/muammar/github/app/dist/app.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore 
and /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

That is also reported for the classes: `NotificationReceiver`, `QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate` and others.

I read elsewhere, that placing a `qt.conf` file next to the application [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28828696/1995261) should solve the problem. But actually it does not work in my case. Does anybody know how to avoid this problem?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having this problem, I fix it by doing the following:

```
python3 setup.py py2app --packages=PyQt5
cp -R /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.0/plugins dist/mya.app/Contents/PlugIns
macdeployqt dist/my.app
```

The problem is gone, and it works everything OK.