# PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication crashes after update to mojave with missing cocoa plugin error

Tags: python, qt, cocoa, pyqt, pyqt5

Since updating my macbook to mojave I am unable to create a QApplication object in python2.7

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jan  9 2019, 18:18:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>> _app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['any'])
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Abort trap: 6
```

I've tried reinstalling python and pyqt (using homebrew), I made sure homebrew was up to date and fixed all the missing dependencies in brew doctor (there were a few warnings but they seem unrelated).

I guess I'm missing this cocoa plugin (I don't know what it's for) but I'm not sure where to install it from. I've found a few similar issues but they seem to relate to building an application - I'm not sure how I apply the fixes to running QApplication inside python.

Comment: Have you looked at those questions?  [application-failed-to-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188153/this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platfo) and [could-not-find-the-platform-plugin-cocoa](https://forum.qt.io/topic/98816/qt-could-not-find-the-platform-plugin-cocoa/8)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/42893

Comment: Qt platform plug-in is missing? The generic solution to that is: `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/QtPath/plugins/platforms` and then call executable from that context.