# OMNeT++ missing "cocoa" on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, omnet++

I have setup OMNeT++ 5.6.2, and INET 4.2.1 - using a Mac OS Catalina.

On trying to run `./aloha` from `samples/aloha`, I get the following error.

The configuration mode is given below

`./configure WITH_TKENV=no WITH_QTENV=yes WITH_OSG=no`
and then did `make`
I get the following error :
`This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. zsh: abort ./aloha`

please do let me know if any more information is needed. Any help or pointer to resources will also be grateful helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188153/this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platfo)

Comment: Have you ever installed `qt` through `brew` on your computer?